# How can I show a list of file in directory on richtextbox when copy file and folder

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show the list of files in directory but I don't know where is

```
 static public void CopyFolder(string sourceFolder, string destFolder)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(destFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);
                foreach (string file in files)
                {

                    string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
                    File.Copy(file, dest);

                }
                string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceFolder);
                foreach (string folder in folders)
                {
                    string name = Path.GetFileName(folder);
                    string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
                    CopyFolder(folder, dest);
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

this one is button click for copy content in directory

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      CopyFolder(txtselectpath.Text, label7.Text + "" + txtDuplicate.Text + ""); 

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);
string richTextFileList = files.Select(file => Path.GetFileName(file))
                               .Aggregate((x, y) => x + Environment.NewLine + y);
richTextBox.Text = richTextFileList;
```

Comment: why when i put this code it show error at Path.GetFileName(file) and  richTextBox1.Control

Comment: what error does it show?. Make sure 2 things. if the file exists at the path specified and richTextBox control is there in your UI.

Comment: Error 2 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Control' and no extension method 'Control' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Project C#\updatexml\updatexml\FormMain.cs 172 34 updatexml

Comment: Error 1 The name 'file' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I have edited the answer. No problem feel free to ask, will be glad to help you.

Comment: can i ask 1 question how show list of content without overwrite in richtextbox i mean append text in richtextbox

Comment: Just say - `richTextBox.Text+= richTextFileList;` += should append the content for you.